# Unix: easiest way of recursively replacing a block of multi-line text

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk, replace

I would like to change the license text appearing at the top of hundreds of source files.
What is the easiest way of doing this?

Edit: Here is an illustration of what I am trying to do:

Old File:

```
License 1:
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx
public class Foo
{



};
```

New File:

```
License 2:
yyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
public class Foo
{



};
```

So, the text after the license should remain unchanged.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the license text same in all your source files?

Comment: Yes. So, if I stored the old license in oldLicense.txt, and new license in newLicense.txt, I want to do something like:

Comment: $ grep -R oldLicense.txt | replace newLicense.txt

Comment: Perl multi-line regexp match shall help

Comment: it would be easier if you gave an example. is the text prefixed with license: or is it just a string of numbers on the first line used as an identifier? probably a tool like `awk` or `sed` would be ideal, but its hard to concoct some code without knowing what I am replacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can identify the last line from the licence1, (so when it is not an empty line or so), you can do it for example with:

```
sed '1,/^the last line$/d' < $origfile | cat newlic.txt - > $newfile
```

Comment: I like this approach because the license is read in from file, rather than pasted into the script.

Comment: `sed` can read from a file, too; `sed '1,/^the last line$/rnewlic.txt' "$origfile" >"$newfile"`

Comment: @tripleee your command will add the content of the `newlic.txt` _after each line_ starting from `1` up to `the last line`. (also works only in GNU sed)

Comment: My bad --- it can be fixed but I guess that's outside the scope of this comment box.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
newText="<your new license text>";

for file in <your files>
do
   sed '1,<number of lines of your old license text>d' $file |awk -v TEXT="$newText" 'BEGIN {print TEXT}{print}' > "${file}.tmp";
   mv "${file}.tmp" $file 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that your "License" text is appearing in top of source files. For this, you can store your old license in a file and your new license in another file. Then run the following bash script.

```
dir=/home/priyank/temp/*.c #for all c files in the temp directory
for f in $dir
do
    filename=$f
    temp="$filename""__temp"
    cat new.txt > $temp #new.txt is new license
    v=`cat old.txt | wc -l`; #old.txt is old license
    awk '
    NR>'$v'{
    print $0 >> "'$temp'";
    }
    ' $filename
    rm $filename
    mv $temp $filename
done
```

Run this as `bash script.sh`. Also, **please save your original files** somewhere before trying this script. It works fast. I took [this](http://www.ideone.com/d3JUG) as the files, and it worked perfectly. Remember not to add any extra new lines in old license file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place to employ an [*ed script.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_%28text_editor%29)

Something like:

```
for i in *.java; do
  ed $i << \eof
1,20d
0r newlicense.txt
w
q
eof
done
```

It's probably a good idea to wrap this in such a way that it checks for the old license. You could make it conditional on a grep for a line in the old license, or perhaps change `1,20d` to something like `/first old line/;/last old line/d`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need this sed command to do that replacement at the top of your files:

```
sed -i -n '/\(License\)/,/\(public class\)/{1h;1!H;/public class /{;g;s/\(License\).*\(public class \)/\1 2:\nyyyyyyyyyyyyyy\nyyyyyyyyyyyyyy\nyyyyyyyyyyyyyy\nyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy\n\2/;p;};};/\(License\)/,/\(public class\)/!p' file.txt
```

Now to do it recursively you can combine above with find (assuming you're doing this in `.txt` files):

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i -n '/\(License\)/,/\(public class\)/{1h;1!H;/public class /{;g;s/\(License\).*\(public class \)/\1 2:\nyyyyyyyyyyyyyy\nyyyyyyyyyyyyyy\nyyyyyyyyyyyyyy\nyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy\n\2/;p;};};/\(License\)/,/\(public class\)/!p' {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a program to do this, which I guess I could share if necessary after some cleanup.  I was clever enough beforehand to have a fixed license start pattern and license end pattern, but perhaps you can emulate this.

It deals with line prefixes, so if your bash files use # comments, and your C programs use //, and your SQL use --, it will put the proper prefix in place (using whatever was used previously).

The other trick was the use of ©.  Some files were encoded in UTF-8, so I could use ©, others were encoded in a latin-1ish encoding so I used the latin-1 character, others were encoded in plain ascii so I used (c).

The final trick was the copyright date range.  Copyright © 1997-2011.  Different generations of management wanted different values here.  From company start to this year, from file creation date to this year, individually listing each year the file was updated in, etc.